# Generic function to duplicate input fields independently of IDs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a GENERIC function that I can call to duplicate a form field to its correspondent copy in an invoice (like in a receipt to be given to the client).

I managed to do it in a field by field basis as in the example below, but then I have to write a new line in the function code to each new ID that I want to duplicate. What I wanted was a generic function that would work across all different invoice types (each a new html doc) that I create and any new fields and IDs I deem necessary.
If possible using plain javascript (I started learning html/css/js for the sole purpose of creating a new invoice system for my small company. Haven't even looked at jQuery yet)

```
function duplicate(x) {
    x.originalname.value = x.copiedname.value;
    x.originalphone.value = x.copiedphone.value;
  }
<form>And the fields:
<input type="text" name="originalname" oninput="duplicate(this.form)"/>
<input type="text" name="originalphone" oninput="duplicate(this.form)">

<input type="text" name="copiedname" disabled />
<input type="text" name="copiedphone" disabled />
</form>
```

My line of thought was making the IDs similarly named and then using a var to find the field to duplicate on. But I'm clueless as how to implement that.
Something like:

```js
function duplicate(x) {
  var y = x + 'copied';
  var z = document.getElementById(x);
  document.getElementById(y).value = z.value.text;
  alert(x);
  alert(y);
  alert(z);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <b>Originals</b><br> 1:
  <input type="text" id="1" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)" /> 2:
  <input type="text" id="2" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)"> 3:
  <input type="text" id="3" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)"> 4:
  <input type="text" id="4" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)"> 5:
  <input type="text" id="5" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)">
  <br><br>
  <b>Duplicates</b><br> 1:
  <input type="text" id="1copied" disabled /> 2:
  <input type="text" id="2copied" disabled /> 3:
  <input type="text" id="3copied" disabled /> 4:
  <input type="text" id="4copied" disabled /> 5:
  <input type="text" id="5copied" disabled />
  <br><br>
</form>
```

It sets y to `x+'copied'` (1copied) correctly but returns "undefined" for z

Comment: well somehow it needs to know what field x maps to y unless you can guarantee order when your query section 1 that it matches section 2. Or if there is some naming pattern.

Comment: My line of thought was making the IDs similarly named and then using a var to find the field to duplicate on. But I'm clueless as how to implement that.
Something like:
    function{
    var1 = current ID /* i.e. id=name */
    var2 = var1+'copied'  /* i.e. id=namecopied */
    var1.value = var2.value
    }

Comment: The solution really depends on what you have in the html.

Comment: see the code I edited in the post. It worked with (this.id). The y=x+'copied' also worked, I put an alert to test it. Just gotta figure out now the y.value = x.value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working, you have only a little mistake:

`z.value` returns the value, but `z.value.text` does not exists at all, so it's `undefined`.

Just remove `.text`, and you'll be right.

Additionally, use the `oninput` event instead of `onkeypress` as it is created for this purpose, and works better (`onkeypress` does not fire for special or modified keys)

```js
function duplicate(x) {
  var y = x + 'copied';
  var z = document.getElementById(x);
  document.getElementById(y).value = z.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <b>Originals</b><br> 1:
  <input type="text" id="1" oninput="duplicate(this.id)" /> 2:
  <input type="text" id="2" oninput="duplicate(this.id)"> 3:
  <input type="text" id="3" oninput="duplicate(this.id)"> 4:
  <input type="text" id="4" oninput="duplicate(this.id)"> 5:
  <input type="text" id="5" oninput="duplicate(this.id)">
  <br><br>
  <b>Duplicates</b><br> 1:
  <input type="text" id="1copied" disabled /> 2:
  <input type="text" id="2copied" disabled /> 3:
  <input type="text" id="3copied" disabled /> 4:
  <input type="text" id="4copied" disabled /> 5:
  <input type="text" id="5copied" disabled />
  <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: I had tried it like you said beforehand and it didn't worked also. The poorman's debug 'alert(z)' I had in place returns [object HTMLInputElement] for the z var

Comment: NOW it works :). oninput did the trick. With onkeypress it didn't work. Saw your edit now :P. Good to know I was on the right path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just adding up: It was basically because of the .text that it wasn't working. But I confused myself with the onkeypress and the alert() that I used to try to help me understand what was going wrong. Because in that case with the onkeypress it registered the first char only when I typed the second (and because of the alerts, I was always trying only one char.

Answer (score 0):

either you use names that are different by an additional string so it is a simple look up....

```js
function copyOver () {
  var formInputs = document.getElementById("form1").elements
  Array.from(formInputs).forEach( function (inp) {
    const related = document.getElementById("ship_" + inp.id)
    if (related) related.value = inp.value
  });
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", copyOver);
```

```html
<h1>Billing</h1>
<form id="form1">
  <label for="first">first</label><input type="text" name="first" id="first" />
  <label for="last">last</label><input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
  <label for="color">color</label><input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
</form>

<button>copy</button>

<h2>Shipping</h2>
<form id="form2">
  <label for="ship_first">first</label><input type="text" name="ship_first" id="ship_first" />
  <label for="ship_last">last</label><input type="text" name="ship_last" id="ship_last" />
</form>
```

or you can do some sort of mapping with a data attribute

```js
function copyOver () {
  var formInputs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-related]")
  formInputs.forEach( function (inp) {
    const related = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.related)
    related.value = inp.value
  });
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", copyOver);
```

```html
<h1>Billing</h1>
<form id="form1">
  <label for="first">first</label><input type="text" name="first" id="first" data-related="ship_first"/>
  <label for="last">last</label><input type="text" name="last" id="last" data-related="ship_last" />
  <label for="color">color</label><input type="text" name="color" id="color" />
</form>

<button>copy</button>

<h2>Shipping</h2>
<form id="form2">
  <label for="ship_first">first</label><input type="text" name="ship_first" id="ship_first" />
  <label for="ship_last">last</label><input type="text" name="ship_last" id="ship_last" />
</form>
```

Comment: The first option you posted suits me better. It's kind of what I was trying to do.
I got stuck at function duplicate(x) {
    var z = x + 'copied';
    var b = document.getElementById(x);
 document.getElementById(z).value = b.value.text;
  }

<input type="text" id="1" onkeypress="duplicate(this.id)"/>

<input type="text" id="1copied" disabled />

In this case it returned "undefined" for 1copied

Comment: I might just steal the first code you posted, but in the process of learning I would like to know why mine failed. Gonna update the code in my question to where I'm currently at.

Comment: ids should not be just numbers and really should not start with numbers. HTML Spec has no issues, but js does have issues

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I got my code working with yours and  @FZs help. I like your script and I'm gonna save it in case something goes wrong with mine. If I understand it correctly, the main difference is yours updates the whole form at once when the button is clicked. I'm going more for a 'real time' duplicate and save yours as a backup for a different project I have in mind. Thank you very much.